# Using Multiple Wildcards for .csv filenames

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a macro that looks for a specific filename and based on the result it runs a specific sub specifically for that file:

```
Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim fname As Variant
Dim filepath As Variant
'filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel File (*.csv), *.scv")

fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel File (*.csv), *.scv",    
Title:="Please select a stat file", MultiSelect:=True)
filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path

For i = 1 To UBound(fname)
    If fname(i) = filepath & "\" & "Nodes.csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open (fname(i))
        Call Node
    ElseIf fname(i) = filepath & "\" & "IOGroups.csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open (fname(i))
        Call IOGrp
    ElseIf fname(i) = filepath & "\" & "ManagedDiskGroups.csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open (fname(i))
        Call MdiskGrp
    ElseIf fname(i) = filepath & "\" & "ManagedDisks.csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open (fname(i))
        Call Mdisk
    ElseIf fname(i) = filepath & "\" & "Ports.csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open (fname(i))
        Call Ports
    ElseIf fname(i) = filepath & "\" & "Subsystem.csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open (fname(i))
        Call Subsystem
    ElseIf fname(i) = filepath & "\" & "Volumes.csv" Then
        Workbooks.Open (fname(i))
        Call Volumes        
     Else            
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I would like to be able to have 2 wildcards in the name, i.e. :

```
If fname(i) = filepath & "\" & "*Node*.csv" Then
```

Is this even a possibility, the reason for needing this is the files come in name differently, but there are root words in each filename that is always the same, the only issue is there is usually something before and after the root word. Any ideas? Also, currently the workbook that contains this macro has to be in the same directory as the files being used to work, is there a way to change this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it? (In a test folder, with a few copies of the actual files, of course!)

Comment: All the things you want are really and easy possible - but what have you tried to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dir` which gives you an immediate list of files in that directory meeting the wildcard (rather than testing every file with `Like`)

```
Sub GetFIles()
Dim Strfile As String
Strfile = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "*node*.csv")
Do While Len(Strfile) > 0
'do something with returned files
Debug.Print Strfile
Strfile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: my +1, but I hoped OP would produce this on his own)

Comment: @brettdj I don't think this is right . OP doesn't want to iterate through all files that meet the wildcard, he wants to check the selected files to see if they match the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

VBA supports the `Like` keyword, so you can make those wildcards work by just using `Like` instead of `=`:

```
If fname(i) Like filepath & "\" & "*Node*.csv" Then...
```

To get files from wherever you want, instead of just the current directory, try [Application.FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836226%28v=office.14%29.aspx) instead of `Application.GetOpenFilename`. `Application.FileDialog.SelectedItems` returns full paths.